# How to Manage Responsive Design in percentage(%)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am building a responsive page layout, but I have a question:

How can I manage width, padding, margin ETC. in percentage(%)?

For example, I want to have my page left side bar `700px` and right side bar `300px` so what property do I have to use in percentage(%).

Here is my code :

*HTML:*

```
<div class="main_div">
    <div class="left_bar">content goes here</div>
    <div class="right_bar">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.main_div {
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
}
.left_bar {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
    padding:15px 0;
}
.right_bar {
    width:270px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: please provide more information about the context, most important: the code you want to aply the % to and even better, create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your issue.

Comment: yes here is code which created by me:- http://jsfiddle.net/u548B/

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This question may not deserve a lot of upvotes, but doesn't seem to deserve a lot of downvotes, either... Maybe it did before it had the fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the issue you have is that your boxes don't stay on one line when you set percentages.

you need to be careful

```
width + left/right margin + left/right padding + left/right border = width of container.
```

like this : **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/u548B/1/)**

Comment: you mean to says that we need to use approx padding and margin in every time, is there any way? which i follow to get exact padding and margin in percentage(%).

Comment: @Mayank I am sorry but I don't uderstand what you mean in your comment, could you explain please.